# How to pass array from php to javascript using smarty 3?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, smarty3

In php file
When I code like this

```
$names = ["jim", "lucy"];
$smarty->assign('names', $names);
```

In javascript,

```
var arr = {$names};
```

Smarty will parse the `{$names}` as
`...&quot...` .

What should I do to avoid this? I want Smarty parse the array as

`var arr = ['jim', 'lucy'];`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In php:

```
$names = ['jim', 'lucy'];
$smarty->assign('names', $names);
```

In javascript,

```
var arr = {$names|json_encode};
```

Notice: 
If you changed your smarty default_modifiers to `array('escape:"html"')`, use

```
var arr = {$names|json_encode nofilter};
```

to make everything work.

Good luck.